# Why do I get an error when using apt-get?

Tags: apt

Whenever I try to install any package using `apt-get install package` it shows an error massage like the one below.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unixodbc:i386:
 unixodbc:i386 depends on odbcinst1debian1 (>= 2.2.11-3); however:
  Package odbcinst1debian1:i386 is not installed.
 libodbc1:i386 (2.2.14p2-5ubuntu3) breaks unixodbc (<< 2.2.14p2-3) and is installed.
  Version of unixodbc:i386 to be configured is 2.2.11-21.
dpkg: error processing unixodbc:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 odbcinst:i386
 odbcinst1debian2:i386
 unixodbc:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `sudo apt-get install -f` to resolve unmet dependencies

Comment: this command doesn't work with 12.04 ubuntu plz post some alternative